# sudden changing of host IP result in crash of the site

Tags: wp-config, options

I have the same problem and the answers which are given above didn't help me, so I explain my situation: My wordpress site is installed on ubuntu 14.04 on vmware This local host IP was 192.168.153.134, and suddenly it changed to 192.168.153.135, so I used this:

```
update yp_options set option_value='http://192.168.153.135/my_site' 
        where option_name = 'siteurl';
update yp_options set option_value='http://192.168.153.135/my_site'
        where option_name = 'home';
```

note: my table prefix is "yp_"
and also I changed my wp-config.php

```
from
define('DB_HOST', '192.168.153.134');
to
define('DB_HOST', '192.168.153.135');
yet still I get this message
```

> Error establishing a database connection

I can't access both admin and frontpage.

what else can I do?

Comment: what if you keep the IP of DB host

Comment: @TemaniAfif it's still the same

Comment: are you able to get to phpmyadmin ? or connect to DB outsite the site ?

Comment: Hi yes, actually I fixed it, but not in a good way, I installed a new version of clean wordpress and transferred db (using phpmyadmin), plugins folder and theme folder, and it started to work

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it,
 I installed a new version of clean wordpress and transferred db (dumped db using phpmyadmin), and also plugins folder and theme folder, and it start working